# How to catch SqlInvalidAuthorizationSpecException in JDBC Template?

Tags: java, jdbc, exception, db2

I have the following code in my Spring Bacth app:

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSouce);       
        log.debug(getPropKey()+"Calling DB for records...");


    List<DataLoadRecordClass> rows = null;

try {
    rows = jdbcTemplate.query(queryStringFormated, new DataRecordRowMapper());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error(getPropKey()+"FATAL: Database call failed wtih : " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

If I feed it the wrong user/password it throws

```
2017-07-17 13:38:31,945 31363 ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization. 
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: [jcc][t4][2013][11249][4.12.55] Connection authorization failure occurred.  Reason: User ID or Password invalid. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000
```

But the above try does not catch it. How can I catch these errors so that I can handle them properly? Right now I can not even tell an error has happened never mind what error or when.

I have looked at many Stack Over Flow posts like this, but all of them seem to say catch "DataAccessException" which I have tried and it has not worked, but catching Exception should catch ANY/EVERYTHING right?

Comment: Either you should write separate catch block which will catch SqlInvalidAuthorizationSpecException or you can printStackTrace

Comment: Already tried that. You can not catch SqlInvalidAuthorizationSpecException (the compiler will stop you) and if you could the catching Exception should catch it.

Comment: have a look into https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/16409/sqlinvalidauthorizationspecexception-unable-to-connect-to-db2-database.html

Comment: That does not help. I am intentionally testing the case of bad user/pass. I am expecting the error.

Answer (score 0):

The try-catch merely wraps a query.  The error indicates your connection pool initialization fails, probably because of a misconfigured datasource.  This initialization occurs outside (before) the try-catch in your question.

Comment: Actually, according to the stack trace the exception is happening on line 304 of my class, which is the line in the try/catch above.

Comment: Perhaps you could share more of your code? I don't see any line numbers in what you've provided so far.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the code is catching the error, just that JDBC is dumping a stack trace before it gets to my error handler and all that noise in the log files buried my messages. Annoying but I can work around it.

Comment: It is not JDBC that is catching it, it is your connection pool (HikariCP) that does this when it tries to add connections to the pool.